# set a char equal to 369 give the same binary pattern than 113 is UB behavior?

Tags: c++, binary

As we all know, a char is 8 bit so it can store values from 0 to 255,

if I initialize a char with a greater value like 369, I get the same binary pattern than 113
i.e:01110001 under MSVC12

Is it a standard, or is it undefined behavior ?

Comment: It is not UB, but implementation-dependent

Comment: It seems odd to me that somebody is aware of binary representations, the (minimum) size of `char`, the concept of `undefined behaviour` - but not of overflows.

Comment: A `char` is not necessarily 8 bits.  There is at least one machine around today where it is 9 bits, and I've heard that there are some where it is 32 bits (and `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that `369 - 256 == 113`.

4.7 Integral conversions, paragraphs 2 & 3:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

But whether `char` means the same as `unsigned char` or `signed char` is also implementation-defined.

So this behavior does depend on the compiler, although most will do it this way.

Comment: `char` never means *exactly* the same as `unsigned char` or `signed char`. It does have the same signed-ness as one of them, but it's a distinct type from whichever one of them that is.

Answer (score 3):

By standard `char` size is not necessary 8 bits and can be both signed or unsigned, so it's implementation-defined.

Quote from C++11 standard:

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]**
>
> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store
>   any member of the implementation’s basic character set.
>
> ...
>
> It is implementation-defined whether a char object can hold negative values.

Answer (score 2):

It overflows. 369 - 256 = 113.

Comment: Same in bits and using bitwise and operation: `101110001 & 11111111 = 01110001 = 113`, which is what really happens (well, not necessarily and operation, but extra bits just getting chopped off).

Comment: is `double` type share the same property ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: no - `double` is not an integer type.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is not necessarily 8 bit. It can be any number of bits, depending on the platform. Even if on your platform `char` is an 8-bit type, it still does not mean that its range is `0..255`. The type can be signed, meaning that its range will be `-128..+127` (assuming 2's complement representation).

If on your platform type char happens to be 8 bit and unsigned, then this behavior is guaranteed. Unsigned integer types follow the rules of modulo arithmetic. `369` is guaranteed to be truncated modulo `256` and produce `113`.

If on your platform type char is 8 bit and signed, then the behavior is implementation-defined.